# Oracle Apex Interactive Report Filter Box

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've been trying to increase the size of the search table displayed when clicking on interactive reports headers.
So far I have been able to increase the width of the search box and the row text but!
I have no idea how to modify the boxes containing the rows (where the list of items are displayed, so if I have a really long item name...the box won't do and the text will be displayed even when the box has ended).
Does anyone know how to do this? or perhaps the name of the element so I can modify it please?

Thanks!

[image: pic indicating what I'm trying to find]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty simple. This question is almost the same as your previous question on how to change the icon size in the filter headers. I briefly explained how to figure out what to change. Here is more details. I'm doing this in google chrome, firefox will work too but might be a bit different:

**Step 1**: inspect the element. Click on the header so the filter comes up, select the element you want to look at and right click "inspect".

[image]

**Step 2**: This brings up the chrome Developer Tools. Here you can inspect the element, see what class is applied to it (main console) and see the details of that class (right pane, styles tab). You can modify the style attribute, or add styles in the right pane so you see the changes immediately but this is not permanent.
[image]

**Step 3**: Modify the css to your need an put that in the css inline attributes of the page.

```
.a-IRR-sortWidget-row {
    font-size: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I know, sorry for asking kind of the same question. Couldn't find it back then but now I did! :) 
.a-IRR-sortWidget {
    width: 60em;
}
Thanks!